# How to plot presence/absence species in a given period of time and place

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've got this dataset

| Period | Place | Species | Presence |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Early | Place1 | Species1 | 1 |
| Early | Place2 | Species1 | 1 |
| Early | Place3 | Species1 | 1 |
| Late | Place1 | Species2 | 0 |
| Late | Place2 | Species2 | 0 |
| Late | Place3 | Species2 | 0 |

I'd like to plot the presence/absence of each species (total:18) into the two different periods and throught the three places, in order to see if there are some diffrence among the time periods and the places.

I've tried to use ggplot and cdplot and this is the last try code:

```
ggplot(Trend_Acquafredda, aes(Periodo, Luogo, fill = Presence)) +
  geom_density(position = "fill") +
  labs(fill = "Species")
```

But this is the result
[image]

Thank you to every one that would help!

Answer (score 0):

One option to show your four variables would be to use e.g. a `geom_tile` facetted by `Period` to show the presence or absence of your species:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(Trend_Acquafredda, aes(Place, Species, fill = factor(Presence))) +
  geom_tile(width = .9, height = .9) +
  labs(fill = "Presence") +
  facet_wrap(~Period)
```

[image]

**DATA**

```
Trend_Acquafredda <- data.frame(
  Period = c("Early", "Early", "Early", "Late", "Late", "Late"),
  Place = c(
    "Place1",
    "Place2", "Place3", "Place1", "Place2", "Place3"
  ),
  Species = c(
    "Species1",
    "Species1", "Species1", "Species2", "Species2",
    "Species2"
  ),
  Presence = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L)
)
```